# Cannot get HTMLUnitDriver Warnings Off

Tags: java, htmlunit-driver

I cannot get the HTML Unit Driver warnings to turn off. The code below reduced the original amount of warnings. Cannot get the last bit to turn off.

I cannot get the HTML Unit Driver warnings to turn off. The code below reduced the original amount of warnings. Cannot get the last bit to turn off.

My code:

```
  LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 

  htmlDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(browserVersion, isJavaScriptEnabled) {
    @Override
    protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
      WebClient modifiedClient = super.modifyWebClient(client);

      modifiedClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); // see here
      modifiedClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
      modifiedClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(isJavaScriptEnabled);
      modifiedClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
      modifiedClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
      modifiedClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);

      modifiedClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);

      modifiedClient.setIncorrectnessListener(new IncorrectnessListener() {

        @Override
        public void notify(String arg0, Object arg1) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
      });

      modifiedClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new JavaScriptErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void timeoutError(HtmlPage arg0, long arg1, long arg2) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void scriptException(HtmlPage arg0, ScriptException arg1) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void malformedScriptURL(HtmlPage arg0, String arg1, MalformedURLException arg2) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void loadScriptError(HtmlPage page, java.net.URL scriptUrl,
                                    Exception exception) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
      });
      modifiedClient.setHTMLParserListener(new HTMLParserListener() {

        @Override
        public void error(String message, java.net.URL url, String html, int line, int column,
                          String key) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void warning(String message, java.net.URL url, String html, int line, int column,
                            String key) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
      });

      modifiedClient.setHTMLParserListener(new HTMLParserListener() {
        @Override
        public void error(String message, URL url, String html, int line, int column,
                          String key) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void warning(String message, URL url, String html, int line, int column,
                            String key) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
      });
      modifiedClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
      modifiedClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);


      return modifiedClient;
    }
  };
```

But I still get:

```
01:12:36.667 [Thread-10] ERROR c.g.h.javascript.StrictErrorReporter - runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: 
01:12:37.264 [Thread-10] ERROR c.g.h.javascript.StrictErrorReporter - runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector: :x).] sourceName=[http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js] line=[4224] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
01:12:38.393 [JS executor for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient@4c085759] ERROR c.g.h.javascript.StrictErrorReporter - runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: '*,:x' error: Invalid selector: :x).] sourceName=[http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js] line=[4224] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
01:12:41.251 [JS executor for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient@4c085759] ERROR c.g.h.javascript.StrictErrorReporter - runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: ':text' error: Invalid selector: :text).] sourceName=[http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js] line=[3983] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
01:12:41.256 [JS executor for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient@4c085759] ERROR c.g.h.javascript.StrictErrorReporter - runtimeError: message=[An invalid or illegal selector was specified (selector: ':text' error: Invalid selector: :text).] sourceName=[http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js] line=[3983] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
```

How do you turn off these messages completely?

Comment: Those are not warnings, they are errors.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid them?

Comment: Do you own the code for the website you are loading with HTMLUnit? If so, then maybe you can figure out what is causing the errors on in the web site's code and fix it there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to Disable logging from logback XML
this kind of deactivation

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

not working, I think they using locgback and it can't be disabled from the log4j config too

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.level = WARNING
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter.level = OFF
```

you need something like that in your logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    <logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter" level="OFF" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: Turning off logging just hides the actual problem and doesn't solve it.

Comment: in that case, the task is turn off logging, you can't fix the javascript error for an external web page from the HTTP client, sometimes you just need to ignore them

Comment: ok, I see what you mean. I didn't look closely enough at what the code is doing and assumed these were errors from the OP's own code.